# Want to disable particular hours slot of a particular date in Bootstrap Datetime picker

Tags: jquery, datetimepicker, bootstrap-datetimepicker

**Want to disable hours suppose (12:00 AM to 15:00 PM) & (21:00 PM to 23:00 PM)
on 20th of April Only.(Bootstrap DatetimePicker)**

When I tried to disable it ..
it applies on all upcoming dates (21,22,23...).

Here is my function..
hours comes from backened...on a particular dropdown change event

```
function setCalenderStart(hours) {
  var str = 0;

  $.each(hours, function(index, value) {
    str = str + ',' + value;
  });

  var newstr = "[" + str + "]";
  var blockedhrs = newstr.toString();


  $('#pdbc').datetimepicker({
    format: "dd/mm/yyyy - hh:00 (IST)",
    minView: 1,
    autoclose: true,
    weekStart: 1,
    todayBtn: 1,
    autoclose: 1,
    todayHighlight: 1,
    startView: 2,
    forceParse: 0,
    showMeridian: 1,
    hoursDisabled: blockedhrs,
    startDate: new Date(),
  });
```

It should be applies on 20th only or any specific Date..not for all Dates.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the datepicker you are using?  JQueryUI has a datepicker, but it doesn't look like you're using that, so which one is it?

Comment: @DougF It is Bootstrap datetimepicker  "bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"

Comment: OK, you will have to go with custom code that gets triggered on an event in order to make this work.  This datepicker doesn't have what you're looking for and I also found a bug in it.  So, capture the event with $('#pdbc').on('dp.change', function (e) {  and grab the date in the textbox and compare that against a collection you will need to construct that will contain the dates/times that you want disabled.  If the date/time chosen is in the collection, then you can take action to guide the user.  Let me know if any of this is confusing.

Comment: @DougF In this datetimepicker we have to first select a particular date (say 21/04/2019) and just after that we have to pickup a time (say 11:00 AM) and then this Date + Time is Populated in the textbox (like 21/04/2019 - 11:00AM)... So i can't grab the date from textbox before selecting the hours because at that time textbox is empty..as i have to block the hours just after selecting the date..

Comment: That's why you use the change event.  You're not grabbing the date before the selection, you're grabbing it after the selection is made.  Once the user changes the date in the picker, the event fires and you grab the updated text from the parameter, which in my example was "e".

Comment: "dp.change" is the name of the event that gets fired that you have to hook into.  I guess the developers didn't want their events to conflict with other change events.